# Using rails jbuilder file in multiple locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am building a rails app and I need to be able to send json from an api endpoint for and android app im building.

I can currently get the json I need from a different controller but I am trying to condense all my api calls to one api controller.

my JBuilder file looks like this

```
json.array!(@rivers) do |river|
  json.extract! river, :id, :name, :section, :difficulty, :cfs, :details, :state, :put_in, :take_out, :picture
  json.has_alert has_alert? river
end
```

It is currently getting used from my rivers controller index action

```
  def index
    if !params[:commit].nil?
      @rivers = search params
      if @rivers.nil?
        @rivers = []
      end
    else
      @rivers = River.where(approved: true)
    end
  end
```

I have an identical copy of the JBuilder file to be used by the api river action

```
  def rivers
    river_list = search params
    if river_list.nil?
      river_list = []
    end
  end
```

I want to be able to render the custom json the the jbuilder file gets me. I have been able to render json from the api controller using

```
render json: river_list
```

But it gives me more information that I don't actually want. Is there anyway to render custom json without using the jbuilder. The important part is that i need a json array

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render the specific jbuilder view file, you can call it like this

`render json: "name_of_the_jbuilder_file"`

So your rivers method would look like this

```
  def rivers
    river_list = search params
    if river_list.nil?
      river_list = []
    end
    render template: "jbuilder_filename"
  end
```

Take note that your jbuilder file needs the instance varialbe `@rivers`, but the `rivers` method don't have the `@rivers` instance variable so this would fail, you should instantiate the instance variable first to render the json successfully.

Edit

Sorry, please use `render template: "jbuilder_filename"` instead of `render json`

Comment: So when I tried this it just rendered the file name directly as json

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect answer, I have updated my answer. Please use `render template: "filename"` instead.

Comment: I got it to work with just render "filename". Thanks for the help